# Keyframe animation display block/none

Tags: css, keyframe

I try to use keyframe for show/hide menu with opacity and display property but the display property doesn't change at the end of animation..this is my code, here is the mistake?

```
#menu {
    background-color: #c1e5ff;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

    display: none;

    -moz-animation: close_menu 600ms forwards;
    -webkit-animation: close_menu 600ms forwards;
    -o-animation: close_menu 600ms forwards;
    -ms-animation: close_menu 600ms forwards;
    animation: close_menu 600ms forwards;
}

#menu.open {
    display: block;

   -moz-animation: open_menu 600ms forwards;
   -webkit-animation: open_menu 600ms forwards;
   -o-animation: open_menu 600ms forwards;
   -ms-animation: open_menu 600ms forwards;
    animation: open_menu 600ms forwards;
}


@-moz-keyframes open_menu {
    0% {
        opacity:0;
        display: none;
    }
    1% {
        opacity:0;
        display: block;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:1;
        display: block;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes open_menu {
    0% {
        opacity:0;
        display: none;
    }
    1% {
        opacity:0;
        display: block;
    }   
    100% {
        opacity:1;
        display: block;
    }
}

@keyframes open_menu {
    0% {
        opacity:0;
        display: none;
    }
    1% {
        opacity:0;
        display: block;
    }   
    100% {
        opacity:1;
        display: block;
    }
}


@-moz-keyframes close_menu {
    0% {
        opacity:1;
        display: block;
    }
    99% {
        opacity:0;
        display: block;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:0;
        display: none;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes close_menu {
    0% {
        opacity:1;
        display: block;
    }
    99% {
        opacity:0;
        display: block;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:0;
        display: none;
    }
}

@keyframes close_menu {
    0% {
        opacity:1;
        display: block;
    }
    99% {
        opacity:0;
        display: block;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:0;
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

because Timing-Function too fast, no mistake
you should set more time at:

```
   -webkit-animation: open_menu 4s forwards;
```